# Issue with running orientdb console on openshift docker container

Tags: permissions, openshift, orientdb

I deployed an orientdb container onto openshift and am having an issue with opening the orient console. When I go into the bin folder within the orient container I run ./console.sh to start the orientdb console and I get this error:

bash-4.4$ ./console.sh
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OSystemException: Cannot access to the input stream. Check permissions of running process
        at com.orientechnologies.common.console.TTYConsoleReader.(TTYConsoleReader.java:113)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.console.OConsoleDatabaseApp.main(OConsoleDatabaseApp.java:168)

It's not an openshift permissions error because after creating a specific dockerfile to create a user on openshift with all the permissions it doesn't work locally.
I can give myself root access to everything in orient except for orientdb/databases, orientdb/config, and orientdb/backup. I think that might be part of the issue but I'm not sure.

If anyone has had a similar issue to this or has any insight on what might be wrong any ideas would be appreciated.

Or if there needs to be more clarification on this question, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Orientdb did you use?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0.8